# Error while adding font-awesome to React project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, font-awesome

I m trying to add font-awesome to my React-redux project. I got the same error as in the link: [Webpack problems importing font-awesome library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731760/webpack-problems-importing-font-awesome-library). But modifying webpack.config.js didnt help. Now my webpack.config.js now looks like:

```
 module: {
 loaders: [{
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
    }
 },       
   { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }, 
   {
        test: /.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
    },  { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
    }, {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
    }, {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
    }, {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "file"
    }, {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
    }
]}
```

And the error that I m getting is:

```
at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (<project>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (<project>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (<project>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (<project>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'file' in <project>\node_modules\font-awesome\css
@ ./~/css-loader!./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 6:312-355

ERROR in Loader <project>\node_modules\url\url.js?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff didn't return a function
@ ./~/css-loader!./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 6:412-465

ERROR in Loader <project>\node_modules\url\url.js?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff didn't return a function
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 6:495-547

ERROR in Loader <project>\node_modules\url\url.js?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream didn't return a function
@ ./~/css-loader!./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 6:576-627

ERROR in Loader <project>\node_modules\url\url.js?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml didn't return a function
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 6:660-711
```

Comment: Does `webpack --display-error-details` give you more information?

Comment: @xjmdoo  I added stats:{errorDetails:true} to webpack.config.js and updated the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would greatly recommend starting with FontAwesome 5 since it's out now.
It's much easier to integrate into a React app and much better and uses SVG Icons.

FontAwesome 5 adds support for React check it out [here](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/advanced-options)

They created a specific package for it. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome)

Install:

```
$ yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome
$ yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

and is used like so

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `-loader` to all of your loaders: `file-loader`, `url-loader` etc. Since webpack 2 it is required to add the `-loader` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

from bash:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
yarn add @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

in js file header

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import faCoffee from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faCoffee';
```

in render function

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
```